# Defining a hashmap as a bean

Tags: java, xml, hashmap, osgi, blueprint-osgi

I am trying to define a HashMap as a bean on blueprint xml. The original problem is that I have

```
<bean id="class1" class="com.acme.Class1">
  <property name="acmeMap">
    <map>
      <entry-key="coyotte" value="Poor Fellow"/>
      <entry-key="roadRunner" value="Sadistic Bird"/>
    </map>
  </property>
</bean>
```

and it works well. Problem is when I have also another class which extends Class1, for example Class1a, on the same blueprint xml file.

```
<bean id="class1a" class="com.acme.Class1a">
  <property name="acmeMap">
    <map>
      <entry-key="coyotte" value="Poor Fellow"/>
      <entry-key="roadRunner" value="Sadistic Bird"/>
    </map>
  </property>
</bean>
```

This means defining the map twice and having to maintain it on the blueprint xml. Is there no way to instantiate, for example, something like

```
 <bean id="acmeMap" class="java.util.HashMap"/>
```

and initialize it with the values I need and then import the reference on the other beans? That would mean acmeMap is only created once. I did search for examples of initializing blueprint bean maps on the internet and can't find one. Or maybe the solution is something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the parent tag to specify the inheritance and get a control over the properties defined in the class. Either you can reuse the same or define the new one.You can refer the below example.

```
<bean id="bean1" class="MyBean">
    <property name="attrib1" value="val1" />
    <property name="attrib2" value="val2" />
</bean>
<bean id="bean2" parent="bean1">
    <property name="attrib3" value="val3" />
    <property name="attrib4" value="val4" />
</bean>
```

Comment: That would mean that "bean2" has 4 attributes (the 2 from the parent plus the 2 other ones defined on it) if I understand it right?

Comment: Yes you understood it in correct way. Bean 2 will be having 4 attributes. You can relate it with Simple Java Inheritance concept.